# Bluetooth socket connection shows no error but does not work

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am trying to connect my cell phone with a modulo bluetooth HC-05, my cell phone asks for connection with module bluetooth and i am trying to establish the connection by the MAC address directly without checking for available devices. I don't get any error but my device doesn´t connect.
Here is my code-

```
public class ConexionBluetooth extends Thread
{
 `public static UUID id=UUID.randomUUID();
  private final BluetoothSocket sock;
  private final BluetoothDevice celular;
  public ConexionBluetooth(BluetoothDevice entrada)`
  {
   `celular=entrada;
    BluetoothSocket tmp=null;
    try {
        tmp = entrada.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(id);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
    sock = tmp;
   }                                                                                       
public void run()
{
    try {
        sock.connect();
    } catch (IOException closeException)
    {}
    return;
}
public void cancel()
{
    try{
        sock.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
    return;
}
```

}

in my class Main i have these..

```
final BluetoothDevice dispositivoMAC = enlace.getRemoteDevice("98:D3:31:60:23:DE"); //HC-05 MODULO MAC
```

For sending the mac to my class i have this code

```
ConexionBluetooth conectar=new ConexionBluetooth(dispositivoMAC);
conectar.start();
```

The class that i am using with API BLUETOOTH, i have more class but are of the application(bundler, BroadCast, etc)

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
```

Comment: My cell phone work as cliente and my hc-05 as slave

Comment: please post the complete code. which bluetooth library are you using??

Comment: bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;  bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;     bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;

Comment: please check device visibility and range

Comment: have you defined in the app's permissions that you are using the bluetooth? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH

Comment: Already i can resolved, the uuid that i was used UUID-SSP, uuid.random only you can use when is a connection android-android in my case connect android device with module hc-05